# Date countdown on gridview

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to countdown the date from today's date on a gridview, so it shows the last 60 days.

I have wrote the code like this but it doesn't work:

```
Private Sub BindGrid()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Date")
    dt.Columns.Add("TallyCount")
    dt.Columns.Add("AcceptedCount")
    gvTally.DataSource = dt

    Dim dr As DataRow

    Dim DateCount As Integer = 1

    Dim DateNow As Date = DateTime.Today

    For j As Integer = DateCount To 60
        dr = dt.NewRow

        DateNow = DateNow.AddDays(-j)

        dr.Item("Date") = DateNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        dr.Item("TallyCount") = 1
        dr.Item("AcceptedCount") = 2

        dt.Rows.Add(dr)


    Next

    gvTally.DataSource = dt
    gvTally.DataBind()

End Sub
```

The date will randomly jump numbers from 6/02/2015 to like 5/27/2015.

```
1   2   06/16/2015
1   2   06/14/2015
1   2   06/11/2015
1   2   06/07/2015
1   2   06/02/2015
1   2   05/27/2015
1   2   05/20/2015
1   2   05/12/2015
1   2   05/03/2015
1   2   04/23/2015
1   2   04/12/2015
1   2   03/31/2015
1   2   03/18/2015
1   2   03/04/2015
1   2   02/17/2015
1   2   02/01/2015
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a loop.  So examine the code:

```
Dim DateNow As Date = DateTime.Today

For j As Integer = DateCount To 60
    dr = dt.NewRow

    DateNow = DateNow.AddDays(-j)
```

First time, it will deduct 1 from today, next time -2 from *that*, then -3 from *that*; at the third iteration it has deducted 6 total (3+2+1) .   Change it to:

```
    DateNow = DateNow.AddDays(-1)
```

Now, it will deduct one day per iteration.

Comment: Not really - if the loop used `DateTime.Now` instead of the previous value it would be spot on. Click the checkmark if it works so this gets moved off the Unanswered list, please.